# How to calculate and curved line from given parameters.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, bezier-curve, spline

Given the distance from the start to the end of an arc $d$, the maximum height of the arc $h$ and some control point to define the type of curve $c$

How might one calculate points on a curve?

**E.G.** $$d = 10, h = 10, c = [d/2, h]$$

$$[x, y]$$ $$[0, 0]$$ $$[1, ?]$$ $$[2, ?]$$ $$...$$ $$[9, ?]$$

**EDIT** perhaps a better explanation:
Define a curve using Distance, Height and attack and decay.
Output Y coordinate for any given X for points on the curve.
I am thinking a cubic Bezier curve would meet my needs. But I am finding it hard to grasp how they work.

Comment: Perhaps an illustration would help to explain what you are asking.

Comment: Lots of googling leads me to believe that what I need is to understand Bezier curves.

Imagine a ballistic trajectory where I can define where the cannonball will land (d) and the maximum height it reaches(h).
Assuming that the maximum height is reached halfway along its horizontal journey(d/2).

What I need is a way of calculating the y value for any given x.

I would also like to define the curve leading to the max height. So the difference between a linear slope 
[0, 0] ... [d/2, h] ... [d, 0]

Comment: Are you talking about the path a projectile follows when thrown or shot? That is what your initial question seemed to indicate.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to calculate it using Earth gravity. I am pretty certain now that what I need is a quadratic bezier curve. Where the [end point] = [start point + distance] and I have a control point to change the curve. I am making animated spheres 'jumping'.

Comment: Non-rational quadratic Bézier curves are parabolas, and parabolas are the paths that projectiles follow under a constant gravitational acceleration. Quadratic Bézier curves should do just fine.

Comment: Thank you :D How much simpler would that have gone if I had found the word parabolas? It was on the tip of my tongue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for a parabola, then the equation for the curve would be
$$
y=\frac{4h}{d^2}x\left(d-x\right)
$$